# In Transit visa for Kuwait

Tags: visas, transit, airlines, kuwait

We are India citizens travelling from India to London through Kuwait & Istanbul but with different airlines(Indigo, Pegasus). We have to collect the luggage in Kuwait & check in again at Kuwait.
Do we need in transit visa?

Answer (score 1):

You have to take a transit visa.

My advice: Its more of a hassle. Try to reorganize your flight, if you can.